# Is レリゴる likely to be understood, and what does it mean?

Tags: meaning, loanwords

Last year, I heard from other English speakers about the katakana verb レリゴる. It's supposed to be a verb related to the movie [Frozen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frozen_%282013_film%29) ([アナと雪の女王](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A2%E3%83%8A%E3%81%A8%E9%9B%AA%E3%81%AE%E5%A5%B3%E7%8E%8B)).

Is the verb generally understood by Japanese speakers? I tried searching weblio and jisho.org for レリゴる, レリゴ, or レリゴー, but couldn't get any relevant matches. Also, I tried doing a google search for レリゴる and the matches I got didn't seem to include the verb.

Also, what does it mean? Does it mean [to watch Frozen](https://twitter.com/akokitamura/status/468207904827252736) ([link to tweet pictured within the tweet](https://twitter.com/miusakamoto/status/468001394322976768)), or to [sing "Let It Go"](https://twitter.com/adamliaw/status/539932019057098753)?

Comment: Since レリゴー is the name of the song (Let it Go), I would assume レリゴる would mean to sing it. Have no idea though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jokingly coining such verb using a title/character of a movie/anime/book is not uncommon among native speakers, but many of them are one-time jokes which will be forgotten soon. Only a few of them (including [マミる](http://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E3%83%9E%E3%83%9F%E3%82%8B) = to have one's head mutilated; to die a tragic death) will be widely recognized and gain specific definitions.

I don't think the verb レリゴる itself caught on last year. So the actual meaning would purely depend on the context. I think people *may* use it at least in three ways:

> - （カラオケで）「何歌う？」「レリゴっちゃう？」 = To sing *Let it Go*
> - （映画館の前で）「何観ようか？」「もう1回、レリゴるとか？」 = To watch *Frozen*
> - 「まだ気にしてるの？　レリゴっちゃいなよ！」 = To let it go, to forget

EDIT: Please note that these are more like possible jokes rather than normal conversations.

Comment: I could not imagine a Japanese speaker saying ANY one of the three in real life.

Comment: この言葉自体が冗談にしか聞こえないのは確かですねえ。現に使った人はいるし、こういう冗談を言いあう若者を想像すること想像することくらいはできますが…。ちなみにうちの40代の職場の先輩はよく「タリってきます」と言ってます。Tully's行ってくるという意味で。